# Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ]

Tags: solidity, testing

```
const { getNamedAccounts, deployments, ethers, network } = require("hardhat")
const { developmentChains, networkConfig } = require("../../helper-hardhat-config")
const { assert } = require("chai")

!developmentChains.includes(network.name)
    ? describe.skip
    : describe("Raffle Unit Tests", function () {
          let raffle, vrfCoordinatorV2Mock
          const chainId = network.config.chainId

          beforeEach(async () => {
              const { deployer } = await getNamedAccounts()
              await deployments.fixture(["all"]) // Deploys modules with the tags "mocks" and "raffle"
              raffle = await ethers.getContractAt("Raffle", deployer)
              vrfCoordinatorV2Mock = await ethers.getContractAt("VRFCoordinatorV2Mock", deployer) // Returns a new connection to the VRFCoordinatorV2Mock contract
          })

          describe("constructor", async function () {
              it("initializes the raffle correctly", async () => {
                  // Ideally, we make our tests have just 1 assert per "it"
                  // And ideally, we'd make this check everything
                  const raffleState = (await raffle.getRaffleState()).toString()
                  // Comparisons for Raffle initialization:
                  assert.equal(raffleState, "0")
                  const interval = await raffle.getInterval()
                  //   assert.equal(raffleState.toString(), "0")
                  assert.equal(interval.toString(), networkConfig[chainId]["interval"])
              })
          })
      })
```

I am getting below error:

```
1) Raffle Unit Tests
       constructor
         initializes the raffle correctly:
     Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getRaffleState()", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)
      at Logger.makeError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:269:28)
      at Logger.throwError (node_modules/@ethersproject/logger/src.ts/index.ts:281:20)
      at Interface.decodeFunctionResult (node_modules/@ethersproject/abi/src.ts/interface.ts:427:23)
      at Contract.<anonymous> (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/src.ts/index.ts:400:44)
      at step (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:48:23)
      at Object.next (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:29:53)
      at fulfilled (node_modules/@ethersproject/contracts/lib/index.js:20:58)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
      at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
      at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:528:9)
```

I am unable to solve this error ...can anyone help me out!!

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct arguments in the `getContractAt`function?  I don't see any contract address given in the arguments.

Comment: yeah!! The arguments are correct....